# Impersonation issue when making web request to other server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, impersonation

I have an intranet MVC.NET website. Let's call it **MySite**. From **MySite** I'm trying to make a web request to another intranet website. Let's call the other website **OtherSite**. Both websites are in the same domain and are running under IIS. Both websites are using:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

**MySite** is accessed by an authenticated user (same domain) with a web browser (Chrome, IE). Let's call that user **Client**. The credentials from **Client**, should be used when **MySite** calls **OtherSite**.

[image]

I have tried the following:

With [`WebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.ImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
var response = request.GetResponse();
return response;
```

With [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx), as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request);

```
using (var client = new WebClient { UseDefaultCredentials = true })
{
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    var data = client.DownloadData(uri);
    return data;
}
```

Both with and without this code around it:

```
var wi = (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
var wic = wi.Impersonate();
try
{
    // Code for making request goes here...
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    // handle exception
}
finally
{
    wic.Undo();
}
```

I've tried with and without `<identity impersonate="true" />` in the web.config for **MySite**.

As soon as I try to impersonate the **Client** I get a `401` from **OtherSite**. And when I check the IIS logs for **OtherSite** it looks like the credentials aren't passed with the request at all.

If I don't impersonate the user it all works great. But as soon as I try to impersonate it fails and returns a `401`. Do I have to do anything in Active Directory? I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725896/programmatic-impersonation-delegation-for-remote-resources-double-hop), where the answer was delegation. Is that the issue? What can be the reason for the `401` I get when i impersonate?

The IIS-logs on **OtherSite** looks like this when I impersonate:

```
2016-10-19 07:33:26 2a01:9080:700:0:3fe7:b92a:552:1246 GET /odata/$metadata - 80 - 2a01:9080:700:0:8d90:4bc0:2ffd:d088 - - 401 0 0 0
2016-10-19 07:33:26 2a01:9080:700:0:3fe7:b92a:552:1246 GET /odata/$metadata - 80 - 2a01:9080:700:0:8d90:4bc0:2ffd:d088 - - 401 1 2148074252 0
```

They look like this when I don't impersonate:

```
2016-10-19 07:57:11 2a01:9080:700:0:3fe7:b92a:552:1246 GET /odata/$metadata - 80 MyDomain\SVC_ServiceAccount1 2a01:9080:700:0:8d90:4bc0:2ffd:d088 - - 200 0 0 0
2016-10-19 07:57:11 2a01:9080:700:0:3fe7:b92a:552:1246 GET /odata/$metadata - 80 MyDomain\SVC_ServiceAccount1 2a01:9080:700:0:8d90:4bc0:2ffd:d088 - - 200 0 0 0
```

I have a service account for the app pool, named **MyDomain\SVC_ServiceAccount1** in the logs above. Real name is something else...

Comment: In order for MySite to delegate the credentials to OtherSite, the user needs to authenticate using either Kerberos or `auth/plaintext`. 

If it's Kerberos, the IIS process will need to be "trusted for delegation".

Comment: @Ben, Thank you. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

If your MVC site is running in IIS, what application pool is that running in?

You may need to set that application pool to run under a specific identity, otherwise it'll attempt to access the remote resource using a machine identity.

**EDIT (in response to comments)**

My next thought was that IIS was also configured for anonymous access and that this was what was being passed. In the IIS management console when you look at authentication for that site what does it say? The settings you're talking about here are about *authorisation* not authentication.

If you try disabling anonymous authentication in IIS (I'd do an `iisreset` after to be sure there are no lingering worker processes hanging around) and leaving only Windows authentication there and enabled what happens?

This is how I perform the setup in my code (note I'm using HttpClient though)

```
protected HttpClient SetupHttpClient(string uri)
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient {BaseAddress = uri};
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();            
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   return client;
}
```

Comment: I updated the question. I have a specific service account that the app pool is running from.

Comment: Is anonymous authentication turned off (in IIS)?

Comment: Yes. `<deny users="?" />`, but I allow `<allow verbs="OPTIONS" users="*" />`. It's in the top of the question.